# How to get a JSON from Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having this problem. I received an answer from a service, and it's data will be different in each call.

This is the object:

```
    {
        "Status": "OK",
        "Code": "1",
        "Message": "Success",
        "quadratureId": "464021",
        "policy": "1559122",
        "initTime": "2020-10-08 11:19:22.0",
        "endTime": "2020-10-08 11:19:22.0",
        "state": "COR",
        "timeCorrection": "2020-10-08 11:20:44.0",
        "register": "0",
        "user": "ADMENS"
    }
```

And, from that, I just need to send this:

```
{
    "quadratureId":"464021"
}
```

The problem is that I am just sending "464021".
This is how I am sending it:

```
$('#quadratureTable tbody').on('click', '.searchbutton', function () {
    var dataTable = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    getDataIdQuadrature(dataTable.quadratureId);     
);
```

This is how I receive it:

```
function getData(data) {
  dataSender = data;
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://" + window.location.host + "/restservice/LIFELOADSHISTORY/resultsquadrature/",
    data: JSON.stringify(dataSender),
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
    
  }).then(function (data) {
      if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#resumeTable")) {
        $("#resumeTable").DataTable().clear().destroy();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#quadratureTable tbody').on('click', '.searchbutton', function () {
    var {quadratureId} = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    getDataIdQuadrature(quadratureId);     
);
```

Or:

```
$('#quadratureTable tbody').on('click', '.searchbutton', function () {
    var dataTable = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    getDataIdQuadrature({quadratureId: dataTable.quadratureId});     
);
```

Comment: The only thing you should correct it's the parameter of the function. It must be getDataIdQuadrature({quadratureId});

Comment: I try this but Im getting this {quadratureId: undefined}.

Comment: Mmmm it is strange. Try the second solution

Comment: Second option worked perfectly, thank you very much.